# C/C++ fastest cmath log operation

Tags: c++, c, logarithm, math.h, cmath

I'm trying to calculate log<sub>a</sub>b (and get a floating point back, not an integer). I was planning to do this as `log(b)/log(a)`. Mathematically speaking, I can use any of the `cmath` log functions (base 2, e, or 10) to do this calculation; however, I will be running this calculation a lot during my program, so I was wondering if one of them is significantly faster than the others (or better yet, if there is a faster, but still simple, way to do this). If it matters, both a and b are integers.

Comment: In the words of Donald Knuth: "*We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil*"

Comment: There were about the same when I checked.

Comment: @You *"mindless mantras are anethema to productive thought"*

Comment: @You - I've always felt that quote is over utilized. Certainly there are a circumstances where you can spend a lot of effort, reduce the readability of the code, and end up not noticing the difference. There are plenty of other cases where you can spend very little effort, not affect the readability at all, and make a huge improvement. Knowing which case is which comes with practice, unless you stop considering the prospect altogether.

Comment: @Mark: That is a good point, but in this case there's probably no need to worry about the efficiency of standard math functions. There rarely is, as they're likely to be implemented in an optimal way on whatever architecture you're compiling for.

Comment: @You: multiply, add, and subtract are all *much* faster than log, exp, and trig.  Sqrt and divide are in between.  (Intel Skylake has a *very* fast FP divide unit, but it's still [a factor of 8 worse throughput, and a factor of ~3 worse latency than FP mul](http://agner.org/optimize/).  sqrt is only slightly slower).  It's a lot faster to check a geometric mean as `(x^2+y^2) < maxdistance^2` instead of `sqrt(x^2+y^2) < maxdistance`, esp. if you're doing this check repeatedly (like in a Mandelbrot inner loop), or with integers.  (x86 scalar integer division is slower than SIMD FP division.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes, I know that. My point is (and was, five years ago when this was first posted) this: Starting with the most obvious expression makes your code more maintainable. If that turns out to be too slow (most of the time it won't, because it's not a critical path of your code or the compiler is able to optimize), apply suitable transformations which you also clearly document. **Measure first, _then_ worry about optimization.**

Comment: @You: I disagree with the philosophy of being totally performance-agnostic when first writing.  I think both ways are more or less equally readable for the example I gave, which is why I chose it.  I can usually think of a ton of ways to do something, and having some idea about which will probably perform better actually helps me pick between ones that are equally readable and short.  I've always liked efficient stuff, and couldn't stop myself from thinking about it, so part of that is just my way of thinking, and wouldn't work well for everyone.

Comment: I'm not advocating sacrifices in maintainability or readability (until after you measure and decide to look for a speedup).  I hate the argument that every performance choice comes with a sacrifice in readability, because it's often not true.  **My point** was that it's not a question of trying to beat the math library implementations of functions, it's about **choosing the right pieces from that set of building blocks, and putting them together so you use the expensive ones less.**

Comment: By all menas if you can think of two obvious ways to do something and one of them involves fewer/simpler operations then use that one. But don't go out of your way to optimize unless you have profiled and identified an actual issue; the compiler is probably more clever than you (especially for hardware-specific optimizations).

Comment: @You That is a partial and indeed selective quotation. I suggest you read the rest of it, particularly the final sentence. The full quotation is as follows: *'Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.'*

Comment: @EJP: Yes, and you have to measure to know which 3% are critical and therefore warrant manual optimization.

Comment: I like [Linus Torvald's ideas on writing nice code](http://meta.slashdot.org/story/12/10/11/0030249/linus-torvalds-answers-your-questions).  It's pretty similar to what I was saying.  "*So there's lots of pride in doing the small details right. It may not be big and important code, but I do like seeing code where people really thought about the details, and clearly also were thinking about the compiler being able to generate efficient code (rather than hoping that the compiler is so smart that it can make efficient code* despite *the state of the original source code).*"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `b` and `a` are integers, you can use all the glory of [bit twiddling](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious) to find their logs to the base 2. Here are some:

- Find the log base 2 of an integer with the MSB N set in O(N) operations (the obvious way)
- Find the integer log base 2 of an integer with an 64-bit IEEE float
- Find the log base 2 of an integer with a lookup table
- Find the log base 2 of an N-bit integer in O(lg(N)) operations
- Find the log base 2 of an N-bit integer in O(lg(N)) operations with multiply and lookup

I'll leave it to you to choose the best "fast-log" function for your needs.

Comment: Cool link. I wonder if any of those methods are faster than the straight-forward ones on modern processors?

Comment: @MarkRansom: They'll all be much slower than using a hardware instruction to count leading zeros, [which all modern architectures have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set#Hardware_support), because the looping methods will branch-mispredict with different inputs.  The hw insn is very cheap.  x86's original `bsr` is clunky (undefined if input is 0), but does give the log2 result directly, instead of 32-log2(a).  Only quite recent CPUs support `lzcnt`, which is defined for `0`.  AVX512CD will introduce `VPLZCNTD`, which does it on every element in a vector of integers.

Comment: Also, I thought the OP was looking for a solution that didn't round / truncate intermediate results to integer.  Sure the starting values are integer, but `integer_log2(uint32_t)` only has a range of 0..32, so the fractional part makes a *big* difference.  There's a huge range of numbers between 2^30 and 2^31, but they all have the same ilog2.

Answer (score 15):

First, precalculate `1.0/log(a)` and multiply each `log(b)` by that expression instead.

**Edit:** I originally said that the natural logarithm (base e) would be fastest, but others state that base 2 is supported directly by the processor and would be fastest. I have no reason to doubt it.

**Edit 2:** I originally assumed that `a` was a constant, but in re-reading the question that is never stated. If so then there would be no benefit to precalculating. If it is however, you can maintain readability with an appropriate choice of variable names:

```
const double base_a = 1.0 / log(a);
for (int b = 0; b < bazillions; ++b)
    double result = log(b) * base_a;
```

Strangely enough Microsoft doesn't supply a base 2 log function, which explains why I was unfamiliar with it. Also the [x86 instruction for calculating logs](http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoca.html#section-A.73) includes a multiplication automatically, and the constants required for the different bases are also available via an [optimized instruction](http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoca.html#section-A.73), so I'd expect the 3 different log functions to have identical timing (even base 2 would have to multiply by 1).

Comment: +1 Nice observation. Although the other answer has a point since these operations are so fast anyway optimizing it is a little much.

Comment: @Jesus Ramos, I always give the question the benefit of the doubt. I've worked on pixel operations that are performed millions at a time when the user expects instant results, and it doesn't take much imagination to think that someone else might have similar constraints.

Comment: That's true but optimization by newer compilers almost removes the need to do some of these things which is kind of sad. Although most people still write out optimizations like these.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the logarithm to base 2 is the fastes, since its the only one to have its own assembler instruction (at least in 8087 instruction set).

Comment: @Jesus Ramos, I don't think that divides by a constant are often replaced with multiplies by the inverse, since the compiler can't guarantee that the lowest bits of the result would be identical. I think divides are still slower than multiplies, even on modern processors, and you would notice a difference.

Comment: I think what happens in some (at least ICC does this for some instructions) is see the repetitive used value and save that into memory so if log(constant) is being used a lot it gets calculated once and stored somewhere so its not always recalculated.

Comment: @Mark: exactly correct.  Unless a flag like `fast-math` is set, the compiler cannot replace division with a reciprocal multiply (not only because it changes rounding, but also because it can cause spurious overflows and NaNs).  And yes, divide is *much* slower than multiplication on most current processors.

Comment: The log instructions are unlikely to be used by modern compilers, as they are inaccurate (relative to what you can do in software) and only available in the deprecated x87 instruction set.

Answer (score 4):

On the platforms for which I have data, `log2` is very slightly faster than the others, in line with my expectations.  Note however, that the difference is *extremely* slight (only a couple percent).  This is really not worth worrying about.

Write an implementation that is clear.  Then measure the performance.

Answer (score 1):

In the 8087 instruction set, there is only an instruction for the logarithm to base 2, so I would guess this one to be the fastest.

Of course this kind of question depends largely on your processor/architecture, so I would suggest to make a simple test and time it.

Comment: On modern x86 processors, it turns out that good software log implementations are faster than the hardware log instruction, so the base used in that instruction is really of no consequence to the question.

Comment: @Stephen Canon, if you have a link to some timing results this would be a great place to trot it out.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, the Intel Optimization Manual lists `fyl2x` as having a throughput of 1 result every 85 cycles, and a latency of between 140 and 190 cycles.  By contrast, using the system math library on OSX on my MacBook Pro, I measure `log2( )` as having a latency of ~72 cycles and throughput of 1 result every 46 cycles.  So the software implementation is approximately twice as fast here.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

- it depends
- profile it

You don't even mention your CPU type, the variable type, the compiler flags, the data layout. If you need to do lot's of these in parallel, I'm sure there will be a SIMD option. Your compiler *will* optimize that as long as you use alignment and clear simple loops (or valarray if you like archaic approaches).

Chances are, the intel compiler has specific tricks for intel processors in this area.

If you really wanted you could use CUDA and leverage GPU.

I suppose, if you are unfortunate enough to lack these instruction sets [you could go down at the bit fiddling level](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogFloat) and write an algorithm that [does a nice approximation](http://books.google.com/books?id=M2QYbTVd0VgC&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=fiddling%20logarithm%20bit&source=bl&ots=K5nTbxsHYT&sig=_AP16WYLsl2vw7uH7KdjV9ofPTU&hl=en&ei=l1kbTp3sA4-VOpjz7PUI&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false). In this case, I can bet more than one apple-pie that 2-log is going to be faster than any other base-log